# Having trouble with connecting to local database ,using my connection string

Tags: security, service, windows-services, connection-string

I have a windows service application that I am running. I can successfully connect to an external server and run the windows service, however when I try and connect to my local sql database the connection fails and I am not sure why.

**This is the connection string that works to connect to external server**

```
<add name="MarketingDBEntitiesModel" connectionString="Data Source=184.17.0.38;Initial catalog=MarketingDB;User ID=John;Password=JohnDoe#4321;Connection Timeout=0" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**and this is the connection string that is failing to connect to local instance**

```
   <add name="MarketingDBEntitiesModel" connectionString="Data source=local;Initial catalog=MarketingDB;integrated security=True;Connection Timeout=0" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: No need for the <sql> tag here, add one for the dbms instead.

Comment: Try to substitute the local ip or localhost insted of local